# How to active scan (ascan) multiple urls

Tags: owasp, zap

I'm trying to do active scan with zap proxy. The code looks like:

```
// /spider/action/scan/ and wait till it finishes
int scanId = StartScanning(clientApi, API_KEY, "https://contosco.com/Home.aspx");
PollTheSpiderTillCompletion(clientApi, scanId);

// /ascan/action/scan/ and wait till it finishes
int activeScanId = StartActiveScanning(clientApi, API_KEY, "https://contosco.com/Home.aspx");
PollTheActiveScannerTillCompletion(clientApi, activeScanId);
```

The spider correctly walks through all urls in the application. However the active scan hits just the first url and stops. Is there a way how to actively scan all the urls (or should I get the spider report first and then iterate trough the spider report and ascan every single url from spider report) ?

Full source:

```
private static int StartScanning(ClientApi api, string apiKey, string url)
{
  var apiResponse = api.spider.scan(apiKey, url, "");
  string scanid = ((ApiResponseElement)apiResponse).Value;
  return int.Parse(scanid);
}

private static int StartActiveScanning(ClientApi api, string apiKey, string url)
{
  var apiResponse = api.ascan.scan(apiKey, url, "true", "", "", "", "");
  string activeScanId = ((ApiResponseElement)apiResponse).Value;
  return int.Parse(activeScanId);
}

private static void PollTheSpiderTillCompletion(ClientApi api, int scanid)
{
  int spiderProgress;
  while (true)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    spiderProgress = int.Parse(((ApiResponseElement)api.spider.status(Convert.ToString(scanid))).Value);
    if (spiderProgress >= 100)
      break;
  }

  Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

private static void PollTheActiveScannerTillCompletion(ClientApi api, int activeScanId)
{
  int activeScannerprogress;
  while (true)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    activeScannerprogress = int.Parse(((ApiResponseElement)api.ascan.status(Convert.ToString(activeScanId))).Value);
    if (activeScannerprogress >= 100)
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which client library are you using?

You should wait until the spider completes, but 'PollTheSpiderTillCompletion' implies that is happenning.

In the underlying ZAP API you need to specify whether or not the active scanner should recurse into the child pages. I suspect your code isnt doing that, but I dont recognise that API so dont know if its hapenning.

Comment: I'm using the .NET api (although that really doesn't matter :)) I have the recurse set to true. I think I've solved the problem - the ascan recurse url was https://contosco.com/Home.aspx (root url for spider) and it should be https://contosco.com (just the domain root).

Comment: Glad its sorted now :)